# Setting Base class attribute from outside

Tags: c#, design-patterns

I want use a base class property in my derived classes. Also, I have to pass the property value from outside. I can think of the following two approaches:

Approach 1:

```
class Mydata
{

}
class Converter1:Converter
{
    void Converter1(Mydata data1)
    {
        data = data1;
    }
    public void Convert()
    {
       // USING "data" here
    }
}

class Converter2 : Converter
{
    void Converter2(Mydata data2)
    {
        data = data1;
    }
    public void Convert()
    {

            //USING "data" here

    }
}
```

When creating the objects I can create like following:

```
   Mydata data1 =new  Mydata()
   Mydata data2 =new  Mydata()
   Coverter cObj= Converter1(data1 )
   cObj.Convert()
   Coverter cObj1= Converter2(data2 )
   cObj1.Convert();
```

Approach 2:

```
class Mydata
{

}
class Covnerter1:Converter
{
    public void Convert()
    {
        // USING "data" here
    }
}

class Converter2 : Converter
{

    public void Convert()
    {
         // USING "data" here

    }
}
```

When creating the objects I can create like following and the set the property value in the base class.

```
    Mydata data1 =new  Mydata()
   Mydata data2 =new  Mydata()
   Coverter cObj= Converter1()
   cObj.data = data1; 
   cObj.Convert()  
   Coverter cObj1= Converter2()
   cObj1.data =data2
    cObj1.Convert()
```

Which approach is better? Or any other better approach?

Comment: What is your criteria for "better"? More readable? (Note that your sample is somewhat strange as one would likely expect `Convert` method to at least return result of conversion, and possibly take some input...)

Comment: I'd pass your data as a parameter to the convert method. Passing it to a constructor implies the converter is one use, and it becomes a very rigid object if you can't change the data in the call to Convert.

Comment: The second approach is definitely not correct (IMO), as that allows users to call the `Convert` method without having yet set the `data` property, most likely leading to errors.

Answer (score 1):

Ignoring the "Converter" strangeness...

In terms of "better as sharing more code and encapsulating data": Often if you need to set property of base class you can do it via base class constructor:

```
class Base
{  
    public MyData { get; private set; }
    public Base(MyData data)
    {
       MyData = data;
    }
}

class Derived : Base
{ 
    public Derived(MyData data):base(data)
    {}

    // Methods that use MyData here...
}
```